# How would I save a complex plot to an object?

Tags: r, plot

How would I save a complex plot to an object?

Let's say I write a function to do some plotting.

```
x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(1,2,3)
p = c(2,3,5)

PlotFun = function(x,y,p) { 
plot(x,y)
abline(1,0)
points(p)
}

PlotFun(x,y,p)
```

How would I get it to return something, like:

```
PlotFun = function(x,y,p) { 
plot(x,y)
abline(1,0)
points(p)

TotalPlot = **getPlot()**
return(TotalPlot)
}
```

Where **getPlot** is a made up function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the `ggplot2` package, but I do not think that you can with classical plot functions in R.

Here are some links about `ggplot2` package:

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/index.html

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html

Comment: `plot` does not return anything, true.  What you can do is write all your plotting commands into a script (or function) and re-execute the script.